# Need Program To Verify Video Files Integrity

Tags: video

I have a ton of video files that were downloaded from the internet. Most are ok, but some were not completely downloaded. Is there a program that will tell me if a video file is complete?

Either a command line program or something that can verify all videos in a directory structure.

Comment: Actually, that's a really slow flagging of me...

Answer (score 0):

I found this, I think it should do the trick.

[How can I check the integrity of a video file (avi, mpeg, mp4...)?](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-avi-mpeg-file)

Comment: Thanks. So I have ffmpeg and am generating output from it for the video files. What do I check?

Comment: you would look for a file called "error.log" which probably would be placed in the same folder as the ffmpeg program.

Answer (score 0):

I find a tool that worked for me. Most of the files that I needed to check were mp4 files.

see link below

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_AdminGuide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f29261b7-7ffc.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f29261b7-7ff9

I created my own bat file with notepad with the following

```
p:\flvcheck -n * . *

Pause
```

all files with numbers are corrupt.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.