# How to see if video is Complete and not corrupted

Tags: video

Is there some way to see if a video has good technical quality (Complete and not corrupted)

For example files might not have been completely downloaded as torrent.

I have sometimes tried to see if they can be compressed, but I wonder if there are better methods.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/262409/need-program-to-verify-video-files-integrity?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4

Comment: (The 2 links above are similar questions, perhaps "duplicates")

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee the technical quality of the video unless you worked on it, however there are some indicators.

- These include the size of the files - as a rule of thumb the larger the file the better the quality (but there are lots of exceptions).  One major one is the codec - As a rule of thumb, the newer the codec the smaller the file for the same quality.
- Also for torrents the number of seeders and name of the group releasing the torrent are useful indicators of quality - more seeders implies its better quality - and less likely to be corrupt.

In order to verify the completeness of the download, most torrent sites have checksums for the complete download.  Download a checksum calculator and compare the checksum of the file you have with the checksum specified.

Typically a torrent will work (but will skip or be blocky) even if some small parts have not been downloaded - make sure you have a decent player which can handle corruption.