# WIN10 - How to modify STDERR before writing to an outfile

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch-file

In windows, How does one change STDERR before writing it to an out file?

The goal is to create one log file containing all the ffmpeg integrity errors.

**ffmpeg-recursive-error.bat**

```
@echo off

set "_var1_DoHeading=ZZZ"

FOR /R "S:\#MiscDownloads\test\" %%G IN (*.mp4) DO (
  echo Processing... %%G
  set "_var1_DoHeading=YES"
  echo [a - The value of _var1_DoHeading is %_var1_DoHeading% ]
  for /f "usebackq delims==" %%H in (`ffmpeg.exe -xerror -v error -i "%%G" -f null - 2^>^&1`) do (
    if %_var1_DoHeading%==YES (
      echo ====================
      echo %%G
    )
    set "_var1_DoHeading=NO"
    echo [b - The value of _var1_DoHeading is %_var1_DoHeading% ]
    echo %%H
  )   
)
echo Done
```

**Error**

> PS C:\duplicate-file-finder> .\ffmpeg-check-for-errors.bat
>
> Processing... S:#MiscDownloads\test\test_video.mp4
>
> [a - The value of _var1_DoHeading is ZZZ ]
>
> [b - The value of _var1_DoHeading is ZZZ ]
>
> [aac @ 000001b1848bed40] channel element 0.0 is not allocated
>
> [b - The value of _var1_DoHeading is ZZZ ]
>
> [h264 @ 000001b184936b80] error while decoding MB 60 21, bytestream -7
>
> Done

References:

- [windows-batch-file-how-to-copy-and-convert-folders-recursively-with-ffmpeg](https://mostlybuggy.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/windows-batch-file-how-to-copy-and-convert-folders-recursively-with-ffmpeg/)
- [For - Looping commands - Windows](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [what-are-the-correct-options-to-use-to-verify-video-files-using-ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/573644/what-are-the-correct-options-to-use-to-verify-video-files-using-ffmpeg-exe-in-wi)

Comment: Your question as written is very unclear. The error message is correct, where is STDIN defined?

Comment: This is not proper syntax `FOR /F %%H IN (%%STDIN)`, and what are all those semi-colons supposed to do?

Comment: @harrymc, STDIN is not defined, how do I define or reference the input received from the pipe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, what is the proper syntax for the "FOR" statement? Also, I have removed the semi-colons (;)

Comment: Have you tried typing `FOR /?` at the prompt? Or used Google?

Answer (score 0):

There are no environment variables for STDIN and STDERR.
You need to explicitly pipe them into some other command.

I would suggest this syntax:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ffmpeg ... 2^>^&1') do set "myvar=%%a"
```

The output of `ffmpeg` will become the value of `myvar` and can be used by `%myvar%`.

The `^` is the batch escape character.
If you will need quotes for parameters in the `ffmpeg` command,
use the `usebackq` option for replacing them with back-quotes.

For more information see the
[FOR /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have updated the code in the question. Getting closer to the solution, but now I am having difficulties with variable scoping... :( 

Please help.