# Can I make ffmpeg stop if integrity check encounters an error?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is there a way to stop ffmpeg from processing if an error was encountered?  I'm using ffmpeg to check video integrity by using:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i file.avi -f null - 2>error.log
```

However, I'd like to expand on it to stop the process as soon as an error is identified.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've already wondered about this myself, and `ffmpeg` doesn't provide an easy way to do that. Based on the feedback I got on the [FFmpeg mailing list](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-make-ffmpeg-stop-on-broken-input-tp4658092.html), you can use the global option

```
-err_detect explode
```

This option doesn't appear to work in all cases though. See `ffmpeg -h full` for the option list:

```
-err_detect        <flags>      .D.... set error detection flags
```

The values are as follows:

> Possible values:
>
> - `crccheck`: verify embedded CRCs
> - `bitstream`: detect bitstream specification deviations
> - `buffer`: detect improper bitstream length
> - `explode`: abort decoding on minor error detection
> - `ignore_err`: ignore decoding errors, and continue decoding. This is useful if you want to analyze the content of a video and thus want
>     everything to be decoded no matter what. This option will not result
>     in a video that is pleasing to watch in case of errors.
> - `careful`: consider things that violate the spec and have not been seen in the wild as errors
> - `compliant`: consider all spec non compliancies as errors
> - `aggressive`: consider things that a sane encoder should not do as an error

Comment: Thanks! I will give that option a go, some error capturing is better then nothing :)

Answer (score 19):

In an option:

```
-xerror
```

The command line option is documented as doing exactly what you want.

Add the option and ffmpeg will exit on a stream error (also setting exit value to 1) from:

```
ffmpeg -h full | grep xerror .... -xerror error exit on error
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i want, I believe this is the answer. not the slhck's answer.