# ffmpeg/avconv getting file reports in time not offset

Tags: ffmpeg

Using the advice from [another superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-avi-mpeg-file) I'm using the following to check video files for errors:

```
avconv -v error -i myfile -f null -
```

Unfortunately, this gives me an error in this format:

```
[mp3 @ 0x2161c20] Header missing
```

Is there a way to set avconv to show time rather than offset or to determine the video time from the offset?

Comment: What do you mean by "showing time rather than offset"? What offset are you talking about in particular? Do you need to find out where (as in, timestamp) in the file the error occurs?

Comment: Yes exactly, it looks like the error is simply showing the location in the file that the error is. (Or worse, the location in that particular stream, but given the size of that pointer I'd say it's probably file)